# picking random elements of a string: basic python

Tags: python, string

I am making a hang man game for fun to teach myself the basics of
python and i am stuck at developing a function that completes the
following tasks:
1. function name = letter_guesser(unguessed_cons,difficulty):
now explanation of both parameters;  difficulty reports to two types of modes, Easy and Hard. 
In easy mode the computer randomly selects a letter from the unguessed_cons list and outputs 
set character, for example
letter_guesser('abcdefg','Easy')
'd' (randomly selected)

## 2 option: the player picks the other type of difficulty, Hard mode. This is where it gets tricky,

in this game mode there is another constant called PRIORITY_CONSONANTS which is a list
of alphabetical letters that have priority over other consonants inputed by the user at the start
of the function, so for example ; PRIORITY_CONSONANTS = 'tnrslhdcmpfgybwvkqxjz', so t is the
most priority, so if t = in unguessed_cons it would be outputed, ex:
letter_guesser('atdcdg','HARD')
't' (first in priority constants and present in unguessed_cons)

***** hope that clarifies it guys

What i have thought about:
1. if easy mode = selected;
        randomly select a consonant from unguessed_cons
    elif hard mode = selected;
         no idea how to get the computer to scan and print once it
finds the most higher power of PRIORITY_CONSONANTS(ex, a,b,c,d) a =
scanned and searched for first, then b, etc, until it finds a match
and outputs set character.

Comment: You aren't actually asking a question here. What have you tried, what has got you stuck and what are you trying to find out? Take a look at the "Homework Question" guidelines here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit or ask again.

Comment: Please use punctuation and formatting, this is really unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete soultion, but should give you an idea how to do it.

```
In [349]: from random import choice

In [350]: choice('absderg')
Out[350]: 'b'
```

As python is open source you can look at the code:

```
def choice(self, seq):
        """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
        return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
```